# What is a good module that allows maintainers of nodes?

Tags: nodes, users

Im on D7. I have nodes on my site that represent businesses. I want the business owners to be able to edit info about their business even if they didn't create it and I want multiple people to be do so. It would be nice if I could assign a user to a business giving them per node permissions. Any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [Node Access Node Reference](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_nodereference) for this. You will need to install Entity Reference and create a multi-value entity reference field linking to users you want to be able to maintain your node.